# .net core antiforgery token validation failed after user logged-in with authentication cookie

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to add XSRF Antiforgerytoken in .net core react SPA. Here is my code.

ConfigureServices contains

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o =>
            {
                o.Cookie.Name = "CSRF-TOKEN";
                o.HeaderName = "X-Test";
            });
 services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                 {
                     options.LoginPath = "/";
                     options.LogoutPath = "/";
                     options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                     {
                         context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                         return Task.CompletedTask;
                     };
                     options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder()
                     {

                         HttpOnly = false,
                         Name = "SessionCookie",
                         SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.None,
                         IsEssential = true
                     };
                     options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                     options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                 });
```

and Configure contains

```
app.Use(next => context =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path == "/")
                {
                    var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                    //context.Response.Cookies.Append("X-CSRF-TOKEN", tokens.CookieToken, new CookieOptions { HttpOnly = false });
                    context.Response.Cookies.Append("X-CSRF-FORM-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken
                        , new CookieOptions
                        {
                            HttpOnly = false,
                            Secure = true
                        });
                }
                return next(context);
            });
```

I have send the antiforgery token in the react fetch header => X-Test.

It is working some action method with [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] attributes but as soon as authentication cookie is created by user logged-in. it fails with 400 bad request

It seems antiforgery token is failing if the authentication cookie is present in the browser.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487586/validateantiforgerytoken-in-an-asp-net-core-react-spa-application

Comment: No @joakimriedel the CSRF-TOKEN cookie is created and It is worked before authentication.