# How to secure the app from xsrf attacks and use AntiForgeryToken in asp.net core react js app

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp-net-core-spa-services

I am using the asp.net core with react template for my app. I want to use AntiForgeryToken for securing my app. I can't find any working example on how to implement that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1

[ValidateAntiForgeryToken in an ASP.NET Core React SPA Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487586/validateantiforgerytoken-in-an-asp-net-core-react-spa-application)

I looked at microsft's documentation and another stackoverflow question, but those didn't help me.

Comment: When you use `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`,can you get the token in `<input name="__RequestVerificationToken">`,If you can get,you need to put it in your request,you can refer to [this](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET/issues/363).

Comment: Thank you Yiyi You, but my app is not MVC, it is an API with React JS

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?