# Submitting React form to ASP.NET 6 Identity controller - where to get RequestVerificationToken from?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, .net, asp.net-identity

I'm working with an ASP.NET 6 app, generated with `ASP.NET Core with React.js` Visual Studio 2022 template. I've used `Individual Accounts` as `Authentication Type` when creating the project, so all Identity stuff has been nicely generated.

Now I have nice Razor views scaffolded by ASP.NET's Identity. However, I'd like to build my whole UI as React SPA application, using `react-router`. It means that I don't want to use Razor views, but still use ASP.NET's Identity backend.

Firstly, I wanted to implement a React form to submit changing the user password. Razor view generated for that is `Identity/Pages/Account/ManageChangePassword.cshtml`. It looks like that:

[image: change password Razor form]

As soon as I submit this Razor form, the request looks as follows:

[image: razor change pwd form request]

with the following payload:

[image]

So now, I basically rebuilt this form in React:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";

export const ChangePassword = () => {
  const [currentPassword, setCurrentPassword] = useState<string>("");
  const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState<string>("");
  const [newPasswordConfirm, setNewPasswordConfirm] = useState<string>("");

  const onChangePasswordFormSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Input.OldPassword", currentPassword);
    formData.append("Input.NewPassword", newPassword);
    formData.append("Input.ConfirmPassword", newPasswordConfirm);

    fetch("Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
  };

  return (
    <Form onSubmit={onChangePasswordFormSubmit}>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="currentPassword">
        <Form.Label>Current password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="password"
          placeholder="Current password"
          value={currentPassword}
          onChange={(e) => setCurrentPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="newPassword">
        <Form.Label>New password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="password"
          placeholder="New password"
          value={newPassword}
          onChange={(e) => setNewPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="newPasswordConfirm">
        <Form.Label>Confirm new password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control
          type="password"
          placeholder="Confirm new password"
          value={newPasswordConfirm}
          onChange={(e) => setNewPasswordConfirm(e.target.value)}
        />
      </Form.Group>
      <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
        Change password
      </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

However, when submitting this form, I'm getting a HTTP 400 error:

[image]

the payload looks good at the first sight:

[image]

but I noticed that I'm missing the `__RequestVerificationToken` in this payload.
I guess it's coming from the fact that Identity controllers (to which I have no access) must be using `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute.

If I change my form's submit code to add this payload parameter manually:

```js
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Input.OldPassword", currentPassword);
    formData.append("Input.NewPassword", newPassword);
    formData.append("Input.ConfirmPassword", newPasswordConfirm);
    formData.append(
      "__RequestVerificationToken",
      "CfDJ8KEnNhgi1apJuVaPQ0BdQGnccmtpiQ91u-6lFRvjaSQxZhM6tj8LATJqWAeKFIW5ctwRTdtQruvxLbhq2EVR3P1pATIyeu3FWSPc-ZJcpR_sKHH9eLODiqFPXYtdgktScsOFkbnnn5hixMvMDADizSGUBRlSogENWDucpMgVUr3nVMlGwnKAQDH7Ck4cZjGQiQ"
    );

    fetch("Identity/Account/Manage/ChangePassword", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    });
  };
```

It works fine and the request arrives correctly.

**My question is**: where to get `__RequestVerificationToken` from? How can I send it to the ASP.NET's Identity controller from a purely React form?

I noticed that when submitting my React form, this value is visible in cookies:
[image: cookies for react form submit]

so the React form/browser must somehow know this value? Where does it come from?
Maybe my approach is somehow wrong here? Thanks for advising :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487586/validateantiforgerytoken-in-an-asp-net-core-react-spa-application

Comment: Thanks @Chetan, but it apparently doesn't help... First solution from the answer to this question seems to do nothing, while the second part adds the "X-CSRF-FORM-TOKEN" in response cookies, but the form's submission still fails with HTTP 400

Comment: You need to take the value from the "X-CSRF-FORM-TOKEN" in the cookie created and include it with your POST request to the server (as "__RequestVerificationToken"). This MS page might provide some more clarity: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-antiforgery-features-with-iantiforgery

Comment: @PeterG but does it make sense anymore? If the cookie is sent with the GET request, then what's the point of anti forgery token? Shouldn't it make sure that the form used to submit the POST request is the same as rendered by the server?

Comment: So let me see if I understand what you are trying to accomplish. You have a server rendered form which uses an anti forgery token which (as you say) ensures that the form used to submit the post request is rendered by the server & you are now attempting to mimic that functionality on a form generated on the _client_ i.e. browser ? And, you are now using the concept of anti forgery token which makes sense only in the context of a server rendered form & then apply that concept to a form generated on the client via JavaScript?

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal basically yes, but this is not what I am trying to do, I'm asking what is proper to do here. I have both views and controllers generated on the server (they are part of ASP.NET Identity). I have access to the server (Razor) views (I scaffolded them), but I have no access (can't modify) the controllers. The real problem is that I built all my UI in client app (React), but I still want to leverage these pre-generated (scaffolded) Identity backend (controllers), so I don't have to re-implement it.

Comment: So If I want to re-build these views generated on the server IN THE CLIENT, this will not work, because of the missing anti-forgery token in these Javascript-side forms. So the question is: what to do here? Ignore anti-forgery validation?
The solution I've applied for now, is that within my client-side app (React) I'm rendering these server-generated views (Razor) within an iframe. It does the job - anti-forgery still works as it did + I can re-use the UI built in the client app (React). The question is whether this is the right approach or there are better :)

Comment: @DawidSibiński there's nothing right about this approach, you don't have CORS setup & you don't have authorization headers, plus you are sending sensitive information over the wire such as password (hope you plan to encrypt them). I'd advise you not to go down this road.

Comment: @DawidSibiński I didn't mean to be so blunt. I guess if this is for internal users behind a vpn then you should good, but if you plan to put this out in the wild then I'd be a bit circumspect.

Comment: Thanks @SangeetAgarwal, this will be a privately hosted app. However, my React form is just an example - I don't mean it to be a final form :) It's just a simple example to illustrate the issue. The Razor server-rendered forms are generated by ASP.NET's Identity, so I guess they should be good for production (as I mentioned, I'm currently using them within an iframe).

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal the iframes are within the same host, so there shouldn't be issues with CORS here.  About sending the username/password not encrypted - do you think that ASP.NET Identity's implementation is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

The AntiForgeryToken is generated by

```
HtmlHelper.AntiForgeryToken();
AntiForgery.GetHtml();
AntiForgeryWorker.GetFormInputElement();
```

And is validated by

```
AntiForgery.Validate();
AntiForgeryWorker.Validate();
```

I'd send `AntiForgery.GetHtml()` to the client, and then validate it on the server.

Maybe you can even create an ajax endpoint that returns new tokens to the Client.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. "Maybe you can even create an ajax endpoint that returns new tokens to the Client." - yeah, I was thinking about that, but I think that simply rendering the Razor-generated forms within an iframe in my React app is equivalently good. Maybe even better, because I don't have this "artificial" endpoint which would return me the anti forgery tokens. Especially that the razor pages and my React app are within the same host, so no problems with iframes and CORS.

Comment: @DawidSibiński Another option would probably just to generate your own GUID as an AntiForgery Token, store it in the session. Send it to the client (store in hidden input). And then compare the sent GUID to the one in the Session when you get a request back.

Comment: yeah, that would be my own implementation of anti-forgery validation :) I think I'll stick to iframes for now as it does the job.

Answer (score 0):

> I *suspect* your are missing the `cookie`, can you please check if you configured your cookies for your anti forgery in your

```
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // make sure you add the cookie name
        services.AddAntiforgery(o => {
            o.Cookie.Name = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
        });
        
    }
```

---

or more from [here on Microsoft Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-antiforgery-features-with-iantiforgery), theres stuff on doing it for SPA apps all well further below

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    // Set Cookie properties using CookieBuilder properties†.
    options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
});
```

---

> SPA App

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Antiforgery

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "JavaScript";

    var requestToken = Antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(Context).RequestToken;
}

<input id="RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="@requestToken" />

<button id="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit with Token</button>
<div id="result" class="mt-2"></div>

@section Scripts {
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        const resultElement = document.getElementById("result");

        document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", async () => {

            const response = await fetch("@Url.Action("FetchEndpoint")", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:
                        document.getElementById("RequestVerificationToken").value
                }
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                resultElement.innerText = await response.text();
            } else {
                resultElement.innerText = `Request Failed: ${response.status}`
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

---

> To Debug it, and see if it works

```
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public IActionResult IndexOverride()
{
    // ...

    return RedirectToAction();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this input. However, in which Razor view do you suggest placing this input with token (<input id="RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="@requestToken" />)? My SPA app is a separate React application. I have no Razor views there.